# MIP SDK - failed to encrypt files got - Error in SSL handshake

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection

We start getting errors for SSL handshake, the error is happening only few times but still we want to find the case

The full error is:

```
Failed to send HTTP request with error code 'generic:1' Inner exception: [http_exception: 'Error in SSL handshake']

CorrelationId=b264041d-506a-4ab9-be0f-cc0e15ae45d8
CorrelationId.Description=FileHandler
HttpRequest.Id=27455c0d-602c-42f1-b13c-f67fc4762051
HttpRequest.SanitizedUrl=https://api.aadrm.com/my/v2/publishinglicenses
NetworkError.Category=Unknown
```

did anyone has faced this issue?

Comment: I am also getting this error. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I am also getting the same error with c++ "Failed to send HTTP request with error code 'generic:337047686' Inner exception: [http_exception: 'Error in SSL handshake'], NetworkError.Category=Unknown, HttpRequest.SanitizedUrl=https://dataservice.protection.outlook.com/PsorWebService/v1/ClientSyncFile/MipPolicies, HttpRequest.Id={867EA676-6F43-4206-BAB3-66346E1198D1}, CorrelationId=15af9437-a3fd-4ce3-956f-562aafcc61ea, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile" thrown in the test body

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried in C# but was facing the similar issue in C++ as well so for me, the issue was missing necessary libs in my makefile and I have added the below external libs to fix the issue.

```
- libssl( -lssl)
- libcrypto (-lcrypto)
- libmip_core (-lmip_core)
- libmip_protection_sdk (-lmip_protection_sdk)
- libmip_upe_sdk (-lmip_upe_sdk)
```

**Note: I didn't tried the proxy scenario, if you have proxy you may want to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/faqs-known-issues#error-proxyautherror-exception.**

I hope this helps.